# Creating dynamic span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

How can I create dynamic tags?

```
$("<img />").attr({
    id: "image-1",
    src: "/images/flower.png",
}).appendTo("#" + imgContainer);
```

It will create `<img src="/images/flower.png" id="image-1" />`

I want to create `<span>` tag around `<img>` tag.

i.e. `<span><img src="/images/flower.png" id="image-1" /></span>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
$("<img />").attr({
    id: "image-1",
    src: "/images/flower.png"
}).appendTo("#" + imgContainer).wrap("<span />")
```

Comment: -1 for overlooking [the performance aspect](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13134858/1081234)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to wrap one element inside another. For example:

```
$("<img />").attr({
    id: "image-1",
    src: "/images/flower.png",
})
.appendTo("#" + imgContainer)
.wrap("<span />");
```

Comment: -1 just as for @VisioN for overlooking [the performance aspect](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13134858/1081234)

Answer (score 0):

DOM operations are oh-so-expensive; just prepare the markup you're after and *then* append it as needed!

```
//Before:
$("<img />")                   //#1, create an element outside of the tree
.attr({                        //#2? change its attributes
  id: "image-1",
  src: "/images/flower.png"
})
.appendTo("#" + imgContainer)  //#3, add the element to DOM
.wrap("<span />");             //#4, create and add another element to DOM

//After:
$('<span><img src="/images/flower.png" id="image-1"></span>')  //#1
.appendTo("#" + imgContainer);                                 //#2
```

Here is [a jsperf test case](http://jsperf.com/string-vs-dom) which results in ~5K ops/sec for the first case and ~14K for the latter (on my pretty decent box).

This is not premature optimization, either. If you have, for instance, ajax-populated 7x10 table and you create every cell individually... and wrap them into `<tr>` elements... and then add it to a table, the overhead adds up. Operate on a string and your script will be at least 80 times faster!

Another aspect to remember is that jsperf explicitly measures javascript performance only. If you're manipulating a table, its content will be even more aggressively [re-painted/re-flown](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/newlayout/doc/reflow.html).

Comment: @VisioN: umm... **no,** [that code is even slower than the original](http://jsperf.com/string-vs-dom) - it's all about picking the correct shortcuts and avoiding unnecessary ones

Comment: @VisioN: ಠ_ಠ have you tried it? I had the jsperf link updated in the comment above